# Does $\Bbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O}$ (which factor through $\Bbb{C} \to \mathcal{O}$) induced inclusion map on deRham cohomology?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry

Let $$0\to \Bbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}^\times \to 0$$
being the sheaf exponential sequence, and we know $\Bbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O}$ factor through  $\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{C} \to \mathcal{O}$ (or even $\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C} \to \mathcal{O}$) therefore it induce a map between deRham cohomology

$$H^{2}(X,\Bbb{Z}) \to  H^2(X,\Bbb{C})\tag{*}$$

(or $H^{2}(X,\Bbb{Z})\to H^{2}(X,\Bbb{R}) \to  H^2(X,\Bbb{C})$)

Does this induced map (*) the inclusion map? I found on the textbook this maps seems not to be the inclusion?

---

The question coming form the proof of the following theorem:

Proposition 3.3.2 (Lefschetz theorem on $(1,1)$-classes) Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold. Then $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \rightarrow H^{1,1}(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is surjective.

Proof. Let $\alpha=\rho(\tilde{\alpha}) \in \operatorname{Im}\left(H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \stackrel{\rho}{\longrightarrow} H^2(X, \mathbb{C})\right)$. Then, with respect to the bidegree decomposition of $H^2(X, \mathbb{C})$, one can write $\alpha$ as $\alpha=\alpha^{2,0}+\alpha^{1,1}+\alpha^{0,2}$ ....

---

As we saw in the first line of the proof, $\rho$ seems not to be the inclusion map?

Comment: Torsion groups can't inject into a vector space. The image is isomorphic to the torsion-free part (i.e., the quotient by the torsion subgroup).

Comment: I got it , thank you for your great comment. \I don't know how to prove it isomorphic to the torsion-free part

Comment: Does it help to recall that $H^2(X,\Bbb C) \cong H^2(X,\Bbb Z)\otimes\Bbb C$?

Comment: i got it thank you